# I am finding difficult to write into slave device and read from slave device. I am using SAM4E16C mcu and ds1339a rtc

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, i2c, microchip

The task is to read and write to DS1339a serial RTC. The TWI initializes as master successfully but when I call the twi_write, it hangs and never returns. The initialization part of my code is given below:

```
#include "twi.h"
#include "asf.h"
#include "i2c_driver.h"
#include "user_uart.h"
// Define constants



void TWI_init(void) {
    
    twi_options_t opt = {
        .master_clk = SystemCoreClock,
        .speed = TWI_CLOCK,
        .smbus = 0,
        .chip = TWI_SLAVE_ADDRESS
    };
    

    // Enable TWI peripheral clock
    pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_TWI0);
    
    pio_set_peripheral(PIOA, PIO_PERIPH_A, PIO_PA3A_TWD0 | PIO_PA4A_TWCK0);
    
    if(twi_master_init(TWI0, &opt) == TWI_SUCCESS)
        Print_Message("TWI Initialized Successfully\n");
    else
        Print_Message("TWI Initialized Failed\n");
    
}
```

When i debugged, i found the problem in twi_master_init which is from ASF library of microchip. the twi_master_init never returns as it suck in the loop. I need some help! The read and write function is given below:

```
#include "user_rtc.h"
#include "user_uart.h"
#include "asf.h"


static int DecimalToBCD(int Decimal) {
    return (((Decimal / 10) << 4) | (Decimal % 10));
}

static int BCDToDecimal(int BCD) {
    return (((BCD >> 4) * 10) + (BCD & 0xF));
}


void rtc_set_time1(uint8_t hour, uint8_t minute, uint8_t second) {
    // Convert hour, minute, and second to BCD
    uint8_t bcd_hour = DecimalToBCD(hour);
    uint8_t bcd_minute = DecimalToBCD(minute);
    uint8_t bcd_second = DecimalToBCD(second);

    // Write the hour to the RTC
    twi_package_t packet_write_hour = {
        .addr_length  = sizeof(uint8_t),
        .chip         = SLAVE_ADDRESS,
        .buffer       = &bcd_hour,
        .length       = sizeof(bcd_hour),
        .addr         = 0x02,
    };
    twi_master_write(TWI0, &packet_write_hour);

    // Write the minute to the RTC
    twi_package_t packet_write_minute = {
        .addr_length  = sizeof(uint8_t),
        .chip         = SLAVE_ADDRESS,
        .buffer       = &bcd_minute,
        .length       = sizeof(bcd_minute),
        .addr         = 0x01,
    };
    twi_master_write(TWI0, &packet_write_minute);

    // Write the second to the RTC
    twi_package_t packet_write_second = {
        .addr_length  = sizeof(uint8_t),
        .chip         = SLAVE_ADDRESS,
        .buffer       = &bcd_second,
        .length       = sizeof(bcd_second),
        .addr         = 0x00,
    };
    twi_master_write(TWI0, &packet_write_second);
}

void rtc_get_time1(uint8_t *hour, uint8_t *minute, uint8_t *second) {
    uint8_t bcd_hour, bcd_minute, bcd_second;

    // Read the hour from the RTC
    twi_package_t packet_read_hour = {
        .addr_length  = sizeof(uint8_t),
        .chip         = SLAVE_ADDRESS,
        .buffer       = &bcd_hour,
        .length       = sizeof(bcd_hour),
        .addr         = 0x02,
    };
    twi_master_read(TWI0, &packet_read_hour);

    // Read the minute from the RTC
    twi_package_t packet_read_minute = {
        .addr_length  = sizeof(uint8_t),
        .chip         = SLAVE_ADDRESS,
        .buffer       = &bcd_minute,
        .length       = sizeof(bcd_minute),
        .addr         = 0x01,
    };
    twi_master_read(TWI0, &packet_read_minute);

    // Read the second from the RTC
    twi_package_t packet_read_second = {
        .addr_length  = sizeof(uint8_t),
        .chip         = SLAVE_ADDRESS,
        .buffer       = &bcd_second,
        .length       = sizeof(bcd_second),
        .addr         = 0x00,
    };
    twi_master_read(TWI0, &packet_read_second);

    // Convert BCD to Decimal
    *hour = BCDToDecimal(bcd_hour);
    *minute = BCDToDecimal(bcd_minute);
    *second = BCDToDecimal(bcd_second);
}
```

the twi_master_write is from asf:

```
/**
 * \brief Write multiple bytes to a TWI compatible slave device.
 *
 * \note This function will NOT return until all data has been written or error occurred.
 *
 * \param p_twi Pointer to a TWI instance.
 * \param p_packet Packet information and data (see \ref twi_packet_t).
 *
 * \return TWI_SUCCESS if all bytes were written, error code otherwise.
 */
uint32_t twi_master_write(Twi *p_twi, twi_packet_t *p_packet)
{
    uint32_t status;
    uint32_t cnt = p_packet->length;
    uint8_t *buffer = p_packet->buffer;

    /* Check argument */
    if (cnt == 0) {
        return TWI_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
    }

    /* Set write mode, slave address and 3 internal address byte lengths */
    p_twi->TWI_MMR = 0;
    
    
    p_twi->TWI_MMR = TWI_MMR_DADR(p_packet->chip) |
            ((p_packet->addr_length << TWI_MMR_IADRSZ_Pos) &
            TWI_MMR_IADRSZ_Msk);
//  Print_Message("\nSlave address: "); 
//  Print_Number(TWI_MMR_DADR(p_packet->chip));
//  Print_Message("\nMaster Mode Register: ");      
//  Print_Number(p_twi->TWI_MMR);
            

    /* Set internal address for remote chip */
    p_twi->TWI_IADR = 0;
    p_twi->TWI_IADR = twi_mk_addr(p_packet->addr, p_packet->addr_length);
    
//  Print_Message("\nInternal address register: ");
//      Print_Number(p_twi->TWI_IADR);
        

    /* Send all bytes */
    while (cnt > 0) {
        status = p_twi->TWI_SR;
        Print_Message("\nStatus Register ");
        Print_Number(status);
        if (status & TWI_SR_NACK) {
            //Print_Message("Acknolwedged not");
            return TWI_RECEIVE_NACK;
        }

        if (!(status & TWI_SR_TXRDY)) {
            continue;
        }
        p_twi->TWI_THR = *buffer++;
            Print_Message("\n");
            Print_Number(p_twi->TWI_THR);
        cnt--;
    }
        

    
    while (1) {
        status = p_twi->TWI_SR;
//          Print_Message("\n");
//          Print_Number(status);
        if (status & TWI_SR_NACK) {
//          Print_Message("Received NACK");
//          Print_Message("\n");
            return TWI_RECEIVE_NACK;
        }
        
        if (status & TWI_SR_TXRDY) {
//          Print_Message("TXRDY set");
//          Print_Message("\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    
    p_twi->TWI_CR = TWI_CR_STOP;

    while (!(p_twi->TWI_SR & TWI_SR_TXCOMP)) {
    }
    
    //Print_Message("Done");

    return TWI_SUCCESS;
}
```